# Reading foreign key data in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two model classes, `Chefs` and `Dishes`. It is a 1-to-many relationship. One chef can make many dishes, but each dish can only be made by one chef. These are my model classes:

```
public class Chef
{
    [Key]
    public int ChefId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DoB { get; set; }
    public List<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
}

public class Dish 
{
    [Key]
    public int DishId { get; set; }
    public string DishName { get; set; }
    public int Calories { get; set; }
    public int Tastiness { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int ChefId { get; set; }
    public Chef Creator { get; set; }
}
```

When I click the dishes page, I am trying to display all the dishes with the name of the Chef who made that dish.

If I query like this:

```
var dishes = _context.Dishes.ToList ();
```

I am only able to access the Id of the Chef, not the name.

I have also tried this:

```
var dishes = _context.Dishes.Include(c => c.Creator).ToList();
```

If I do that, `Creator` is the entire `Chef` object, and if I try to loop through it, I get errors as well. Can someone please get me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your loop code so we can see the issue.

Comment: `foreach(Dish thisDish in dishes) { string name = thisDish.Creator.FirstName; // etc }`

Comment: @foreach (Dish dish in @ViewBag.dishes)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@dish.DishName</td>
                    <td>@dish.ChefId</td>
                    <td>@dish.Tastiness</td>
                    <td>@dish.Calories</td>
                    <td>@dish.Creator</td>
                </tr>
                
            }

Comment: I have tried to do it in the way you specified, thisDish.Creator.FirstName

Comment: But it still gives me an error

Comment: If you have a context why use ViewBag?

Comment: ***WHAT ERROR*** do you get? Remember: we cannot see and read your screen - nor your mind - you have to **TELL US!** .....

Comment: Please show the code where you create a new Dish object and assign it to a Chef and save to db.

Comment: It seems you are using ASP MVC. I need to see the code in your controller and the code in your view. Not all of it but relevant code.